# How to get list of macbooks that use office for mac in network

Tags: exchange, mac, microsoft-office, mailbox

on our network we have some macbooks that use office for mac. 
Mac's arent in the domain,but users are using exchange mailbox. 
Is there any way to list this computers? Maybe on the exchange site? Search for specific version of program?

Answer (score 1):

Look at the user agent strings in the IIS logs.